# Filter method of array in Mongodb 4.0.15 does not work anymore

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Some months ago the following script did work well, but I guess due to some update of Mongo it does not work anymore.

```
var individuals_in_files = db.files.distinct("individual"); //what corresponds to the _id of individuals in the collection below. Like a foreign key. You should notice that the "individual" field are in arrays in these files, like 'individual':['_idA','_idB','_idC'].
var _id_individuals = db.individuals.distinct('_id');//_id of individuals
//Filtering
var difference = individuals_in_files.filter(x => !_id_individuals.includes(x)); //want individuals in files that haven't their own representation in the collection individuals
var difference = difference.filter(function (el) {
  return el != null;
});
var text = JSON.stringify(difference, null, '\t');
print(text); //in order to save it in a file for other purpose
```

Line 1 and line 2 work fine. But the filtering at `var difference = individuals_in_files.filter(x => !_id_individuals.includes(x));` won't work. It just says:

```
Failed to execute script.

Error: // yes, nothing is precised, this is empty.
```

, while some months ago it was about the same size of arrays, so the capacity has not changed.

Did JS change in Mongodb ?

---

`db.version() : 4.0.15`

Comment: For reference, what MongoDB Version was you running before when this was working?

Comment: @RobertSeaman Unfortunately I don't remember, I didn't take note about it. And I even cannot access the date of creation of the script, so I cannot give any approximation correctly.

Comment: Where do you run this code? MongoDB shell or other GUI? Since v3.4 it supports ES6.

Comment: @Valijon I runned it in the MongoDB shell via Robo3t. But even only interpreted by mongo like `mongo script.js >> output.json` won't work too.

Comment: Run this please: `new Function("(a = 0) => a")` If fails, your robo3T version is very old

Comment: @Valijon Do you mean to run `new Function("(a = 0) => a")` all alone in robo3t shell ? If so, it returns `function anonymous() {
(a = 0) => a
}`.